# React navigation state.params not working

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, fetch-api

It is not working. I tried everything. Nothing works. `state.params` is simply not there if you make an advanced app.

I have this problem with the react "navigation". It says in the manual that the params object should be there https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop.html#state-the-screen-s-current-state-route But it isn't.

I set an `id` parameter like this in screen 1 when I link to screen 2:

```
 <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={ ()=> this.props.navigation.navigate('FontsTab', { id: item.id }) } style={styles.listHeader} >
                <View  style={styles.listRowContainer}>
                    <View  style={styles.listinside1Container}>
                        <Image  style={styles.listImage} source={item.icon} />
                        <View  style={styles.listContainer} onPress={(event) => this._selectedItem(item.text)}  >
                            <Text style={styles.listHeader} >
                              {item.title}
                            </Text>
                            <Text  style={styles.listValue} >{item.value}</Text>
                            <Image 
                                style={{width: 50, height: 50}}
                                source={{uri: item.img}}
                            />

                        </View>
                    </View>

                                </View>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

But it's not working. In screen 2 I can't use the `state.params` :

```
     <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
          <Text>{ JSON.stringify(this.props.navigation)}</Text>
          <Text>TEST{ state.params }</Text>
          <Image
              style={{width: 150, height: 150}}
              source={{uri: this.state.dataSource.img}}
          />
          <Text  style={styles.textStyle} >{this.state.dataSource.text}</Text>
      </ScrollView>
```

`state.params` just returns nothing. What can I do about it?

The full class for screen2:

```
class Fonts extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            params: null,
            selectedIndex: 0,
            value: 0.5,
            dataSource: null,
            isLoading: true
        };
        this.componentDidMount = this.componentDidMount.bind(this);
    }
    getNavigationParams() {
        return this.props.navigation.state.params || {}
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        return fetch('http://www.koolbusiness.com/newvi/4580715507220480.json')
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
                this.setState({
                    ...this.state,
                    isLoading: false,
                    dataSource: responseJson,
                }, function(){
                });
            })
            .catch((error) =>{
                console.error(error);
            });
    }
  render() {
      if(this.state.isLoading){
          return(
              <View style={{flex: 1, padding: 20}}>
                  <ActivityIndicator/>
              </View>
          )
      }
    return (
      <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
          <Text>{ JSON.stringify(this.props)}</Text>
          <Text>TEST{ this.state.params }</Text>
          <Image
              style={{width: 150, height: 150}}
              source={{uri: this.state.dataSource.img}}
          />
          <Text  style={styles.textStyle} >{this.state.dataSource.text}</Text>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
```

In my app this pain is reproducible by a simple button in screen1:

`<Button
                    onPress={() => navigate('FontsTab', { name: 'Brent' })}
                    title="Go to Brent's profile"
                />`

Then switching to the FontsTab works but the params are not in the state object:

[image]

I also have this code for the tabview

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements';

import FontsHome from '../views/fonts_home';
import FontsDetails from '../views/fonts_detail';

const FontsTabView = ({ navigation }) => (
  <FontsHome banner="Fonts" navigation={navigation} />
);

const FontsDetailTabView = ({ navigation }) => (
  <FontsDetails banner="Fonts Detail" navigation={navigation} />
);

const FontsTab = StackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: FontsTabView,
    path: '/',
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: '',
      headerLeft: (
        <Icon
          name="menu"
          size={30}
          type="entypo"
          style={{ paddingLeft: 10 }}
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')}
        />
      ),
    }),
  },
  Detail: {
    screen: FontsDetailTabView,
    path: 'fonts_detail',
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Fonts Detail',
    },
  },
});

export default FontsTab;
```

Answer (score 1):

`this.props.navigation.state.params.id` will give you the value of param id passed from screen1.

Comment: I thought so too but obviously I'm doing something wrong. When I debug `this.props.navigation` there is no `state` object there!

Comment: It says `routeName: "Home"` when I debug the `state` object. Why isn't the routeName "FontsTab" ?

Answer (score 0):

I put my screen in the right StackNavigator and then it worked.